# What are the negative aspects of Java class Stack inheriting from Vector?

Tags: java, inheritance, vector, stack

By extending class Vector, Java’s designers were able to create class Stack quickly. What are
the negative aspects of this use of inheritance, particularly for class Stack?

Comment: Whoops, I messed up my last comment... lets try that again:  In Java 6, you should use something that implements `Deque` (like `ArrayDeque`) over `Stack`, using the `addFirst`/`offerFirst`, `removeFirst`/`pollFirst`, and `peekFirst` methods. Deque: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One problem is that Stack is a class, not an interface. This diverges from the design of the collection framework, where your noun is typically represented as an interface (e.g., List, Tree, Set, etc.), and there are specific implementations (e.g., ArrayList, LinkedList). If Java could avoid backward compatibility, then a more proper design would be to have a Stack interface, then VectorStack as an implementation.

A second problem is that Stack is now bound to Vector, which is generally avoided in favour of ArrayLists and the like.

A third problem is that you cannot easily provide your own stack implementation, and that stacks support very non-stack operations like getting an element from a specific index, including the potential for index exceptions. As a user, you may also have to know if the top of the stack is at index 0 or at index n. The interface also exposes implementation details such as capacity.

Of all the decisions in the original Java class library, I consider this one of the more peculiar ones. I doubt that Aggregation would have been much more expensive than inheritance.

Comment: Sun recommends using a `Deque` (like `ArrayDeque`) instead of Stack in Java 6 and newer.

Comment: @Bemrose: That is true. However, I am actually not a big fan of that because it exposes interface methods to take stuff out from both sides. The DE nature seems like an implementation detail to me. I guess I'm an API purist. As an aside, I always hated how STL coined the "deque" acronym, since in most accents it is pronounced like "dequeue", leading to some confusion.

Comment: An aside to your aside: STL didn't invent 'deque'; that word has existed for decades. A quick check of a 1973 textbook found several mentions in the index.

Answer (score 29):

*Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*:

> Inheritance is appropriate only in circumstances where the subclass really is a *subtype* of the superclass. In other words, a class *B* should only extend a class *A* only if an "is-a" relationship exists between the two classes. If you are tempted to have a class *B* extend a class *A*, ask yourself this question: Is every *B* really an *A*? If you cannot truthfully answer yes to this question, *B* should not extend *A*. If the answer is no, it is often the case that *B* should contain a private instance of *A* and expose a smaller and simpler API; *A* is not an essential part of *B*, merely a detail of its implementation.
>
> There are a number of obvious violations of this principle in the Java platform libraries. For example, a stack is not a vector, so `Stack` should not extend `Vector`. Similarly, a property list is not a hash table, so `Properties` should not extend `Hashtable`. In both cases, composition would have been preferrable.

The book goes in greater detail, and combined with *Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it*, advises against overuse and abuse of inheritance in your design.

Here's a simple example that shows the problem of `Stack` allowing un-`Stack`-like behavior:

```
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push("1");
    stack.push("2");
    stack.push("3");
    stack.insertElementAt("squeeze me in!", 1);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
    // prints "3", "2", "squeeze me in!", "1"
```

This is a gross violation of the stack abstract data type.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Stack (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29)

  > In computer science, a stack is a last in, first out (LIFO) abstract data type and data structure.

Comment: But what if the object you put on the stack is modified while its on the stack? Either we have to make stack take a deep copy with every push or we have to look more critically at what LIFO means.

Comment: An `ElectricCar` is a `Car`, but your program will *still* be better served if you make `Car` the concrete class with an `IDriveTrain` member, implemented by `ElectricDriveTrain`. In this way, you can represent your `ElectricCar` via composition without the tight coupling brought on by inheritance (in other words, you can test the car responsibilities and the drivetrain responsibilities separately). Inheritance is *never* the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 7):

Having `Stack` subclass `Vector` exposes methods that are not appropriate for a stack, because a stack is not a vector (it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

For example, a stack is a LIFO data structure yet using this implementation you can call the `elementAt` or `get` methods to retrieve an element at a specified index. Or you can use `insertElementAt` to subvert the stack contract.

I think Joshua Bloch has gone on record as saying that having `Stack` subclass `Vector` was a mistake, but unfortunately I can't find the reference.

Comment: See polygenelubricant's quote from Effective Java, written by Bloch.

Comment: RE: LSP - not true at all. Where ever you have a java.util.vector you can substitute a java.util.stack without changing the behaviour of the function. For the record I believe inheritence of behavoiur is evil, but Stack subclassing Vector is one of the *mildest* violations of this that I've encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `Stack` should be an interface.

The `Stack` interface should define the operations a stack can perform.  Then there could be different implementations of `Stack` that perform differently in different situations.

But, since `Stack` is a concrete class, this cannot happen.  We are limited to one implementation of a stack.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the main valid points mentioned above, another big problem with Stack inheriting from Vector is Vector is completely synchronized, so you get that overhead whether you need it or not (see StringBuffer vs. StringBuilder). Personally I tend to use ArrayDeque whenever I want a stack.

Answer (score 3):

It violates the very first rule we all learned about inheritance: can you, with a straight face, say that a Stack IS-A Vector? Clearly not.

Another more logical operation would be to have used aggregation, but the best option IMO would be to have made Stack an interface which could be implemented by any appropriate data structure, similar (but not exactly the same) to what the C++ STL does.