# Why Stack class in java does not throw UnsupportedOperationException on 'add' method?

Tags: java, collections, interface

Its clearly specified that `java.util.Stack` is a LIFO stack implementation of `List` Interface.
One would naturally think since `Stack` follows a LIFO paradigm , it should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when someone tries to invoke its `add` method which it inherited from `List` which in turn inherits from `Collection`.
method `add` is an **optional operation** . i.e implementations are not necessarily required to implement them and can rather just throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` on their invocation.
Stack should have naturally done so, since you can only add new elements in the last, since its a stack. 
I am surprised `add(int index,E e)` method actually works on `Stack` objects!   defeats the purpose of Stack if you can add an element anywhere in it and not just the end

Answer (score 2):

It [extends Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), and therefore supports operations such as `get(int)` and `add(int,E)`. It is a known weird thing and is considered a [design mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922306/645270) by many. What you say about it defeating the purpose of a stack is true.