# Stack using the Java 8 collection streaming API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-collections-api

I have a method which generates an object each time I execute it, and I need to reverse the order with which I am getting them. So I thought the natural way to do it would be a Stack, since it is LIFO.

However, the Java [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) does not seem to play well with the new Java 8 streaming API.

If I do this:

```
   Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
   stack.push("A");
   stack.push("B");
   stack.push("C");

   List<String> list = stack.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
   System.out.println("Collected: " + list);
```

The output I get is:

```
Collected: [A, B, C]
```

Why isn't it outputing them in the expected LIFO order to the stream?
Is this the right way to flush out all the items from the stack to a list in the right (LIFO) order?

Comment: I expect it's because Stack extends Vector (which maintains the original insertion order; pop gives you the **last** object in the Stack).  Do you get the same result using a Deque? ArrayDeque for instance pushes and pops off the front, so it should give you the ordering you want.

Comment: `Deque` (and its implementing classes) doesn't even have a `stream()` method. The question is not whether I can work around it (I can obviously write my own loop). Its why would Stack offer the stream method and stream it in the wrong way, when one would expect a LIFO ordering given the choice of the collection used.

Comment: According to the [ArrayDeque API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), it's got the same `stream()` method from java.util.Collection that [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) does.  I don't have Java 8 here though, so I can't test it.

Comment: Ah yes, I ended up on the JDK 7 version by mistake. So Yes, with `Deque` it works correctly! Why would that be? (I just changed `Stack` to `Deque`)

Comment: Because `Stack` is just a weird mutant `Vector`.  In fact, I think breaking the intuitive ordering when you call `stream()` is something you might want to add to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922257/what-are-the-negative-aspects-of-java-class-stack-inheriting-from-vector.

Comment: I hadn't realised that. They should deprecate these `Vector` based classes once and for all. I tested it with both `LinkedList` and `ArrayDeque` and if I `push()` the items, the `stream()` will correctly reverse their order.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, we have well tested [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface which should be preferred.

But I will you give the reason why [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) shouldn't be used.

At first, the Java Doc. of the Stack says itself:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
> provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
> be used in preference to this class. For example:
>
> ```
> Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
> ```

See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

So what it is the problem with the `Stack` class.

Like Martin Fowler already mentioned in his book
***Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code***
at the refactoring method ***Replace Inheritance with Delegation***,
a Stack shouldn't inherit from a Vector.

> One of the classic examples of inappropriate inheritance is making a
> stack a subclass of vector. Java 1.1 does this in its utilities
> (naughty boys!)
> [6, p. 288]

Instead, they should have used delegation like in the picture below,
which is also from the book.

See also here: [Replace Inheritance with Delegation](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceInheritanceWithDelegation.html)

[image: Replace Inheritance with Delegation]

So but why is this a problem:

Because the Stack has only 5 Methods:

1. pop
2. push
3. isEmpty
4. search
5. size

`size()` and `isEmpty()` are inherited from the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class and the other methods from the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) are not used. But through the inheritance, other methods are forwarded to the `Stack` class which makes no sense.

And Fowler says to this problem:

> You can live with the situation and use convention to say that
> although it is a subclass, it's using only part of the superclass
> function. But that results in code that says one thing when your
> intention is something else—a confusion you should remove.

This hurts the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf)

which says:

> CLIENTS SHOULD NOT BE FORCED TO DEPEND UPON INTERFACES THAT THEY DO
> NOT USE.

---

**You can check out the source code** of the [Vector](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Vector.java#Vector) and [Stack](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Stack.java?av=f) class
and you will see that the Stack class inherit the `spliterator` method
and the `VectorSpliterator` innerClass from the `Vector` class.

This method is used by the `Collection` interface to impl. the default version of stream method:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
  return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

So avoid simply the usage of the `Vector` and `Stack` class.

[6] Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code Fowler, Martin year 1997

Comment: The other big difference is that Vector/Stack (I think all old java.util.* collections) are thread safe. Which means in single threaded context they are nevertheless accessed synchronized, which is much slower than non synchronized access. It is basically the same "problem" why StringBuffer is "replaced" by StringBuilder.