# Read file in reverse order using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Here is the file content :

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

Now I want to read the file in reverse order string as below

```
line 5
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

The code I use to read the file line by line is

```
try (Stream<String> steam = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\..\\..\\taxreport.txt")).skip(1)) {
    steam.foreach(i->System.Out.Println(i));
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(RED_BOLD + "File not Found !!");
}
```

The code read the file line by line in normal order. But I want to read the line in reverse order.

Can anyone let me know how can I read the line in reverse order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read file from end to start (in reverse order) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664705/how-to-read-file-from-end-to-start-in-reverse-order-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010109/java-8-stream-reverse-order)

Comment: You  need to read the file, store it in a LIFO collection then read that collection. You don't really have a "easy" way to position a cursor in a file. So this will be done in memory.

Comment: No reason to down vote this. Above suggestions include non-Java8 and IntStreams. This is text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for strings:

```
steam.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
    .descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

This is another example using `ArrayList`:

```
    List<String> list = steam.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    Collections.reverse(list);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Could we have not used Stack here?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I am not sure what you mean but I added another example.

Comment: Ignore me, found the answer to my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387579/stack-using-the-java-8-collection-streaming-api

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj: you can use an `ArrayDeque` instead. It works as a replacement of both, `Vector` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: Thanks @Holger I will give it a try.